# Three Select Boxes Interacting to Yield One Result - HTML, JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I have three select boxes:

```
<select id="one">
    <option value="default">Select Product</option>
    <option value="value-a1">string1</option>
    <option value="value-a2">string2</option>
    <option value="value-a3">string3</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
    <option value="default">Select Version</option>
    <option value="value-b4">string4</option>
    <option value="value-b5">string5</option>
    <option value="value-b6">string6</option>
</select>

<select id="three">
    <option value="default">Select Architecture</option>
    <option value="value-c6">string7</option>
    <option value="value-c7">string8</option>
    <option value="value-c8">string9</option>
</select>
```

Based on what the user selects for these three boxes, I want to download a file like so, for example:

`mysite.com/download/value-a1_value-b2_value-c3`

Basically, the file is an installer, that can be a certain product, a specific version, and the architecture (using EXE as an example; will have DMG and ZIP too):

`mysite.com/download/product-a_version-b_arch-64.exe`

I understand that my approach may not be the best, so I'm open to suggestions, but if I could get this approach to work, that would be great.

For the JavaScript I was thinking something like this:

```
function download_file(version_id, os_id, arch_id) {

    if (product_id == 'default' && version_id == 'default' && 
        arch_id == 'default') {
        return;
    }

    else if (product_id != 'default') {
        window.location = 'mysite.com/download/Install_' +
            product_id + '_' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.exe';
    }
}
```

I guess my main problem is how to select what select values are chosen in the three select boxes.  I'm trying to glue together the results from the three select boxes and determine a path from that.

**NOTE**

I actually had more select boxes than I actually wrote about,  but the principles are the same.  Using answers below, I was able to get the file to be correct.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: jQuery has `val()` and it also works on `select`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/y2NXd/)

```
​$(function() {
    var downloadButton = $( selector-for-your-button );

    $(downloadButton).click(function() {

        download_file( $('#one').val(), $('#two').val(),
                      $('#three').val());

    });
});

function download_file(product_id, version_id, arch_id) {

    // if any of them is default, cancel (use or ||)
    if (product_id == 'default' || version_id == 'default' || 
        arch_id == 'default') {
            alert("choose stuff!");
        return;
    }

    else if (product_id != 'default') {
        //window.location = 'mysite.com/download/Install_' +
        //    product_id + '_' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.exe';
        console.log(product_id + '_' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.exe');
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I went with your answer, although others are very good too.  The reason is that it used my function, so that was nice.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, I've got another question, and I realized I didn't really know how to do it after posting this question.  Your answer is great, and I am using it, but now I have a situation whereby I'm actually using a PHP function with input variables to generate my select boxes.  Problem is, I'm finding it hard to set up cascading select with these, since they are generated as the page is written.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `<select>` boxes a class:

```
<select id="one" class="installer-option">
    ...
```

Now, you can use `map()` to extract the selected options into an array:

```
var options = $('.select').map(function() { return $(this).val(); });
```

You can test to see if any default options have been chosen using `inArray`:

```
if ($.inArray('default', options) != -1) {
    // There's a default option
}
```

From there, you can `join` the strings together into your final URL:

```
var file = options.join('_') + '.exe';
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A2q47/3/**

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using jQuery's [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function

```
// check if all three select has a value selected besides default - return false if any are default
if ($('select').filter(function() {
    return this.value == 'default';
}).length > 0) {
   return false;
}

// using jQuery's map function - get the values - turn into array - join with '_'
var newString = $('select').map(function(i, v) {
    return v.value;
}).get().join('_');
console.log(newString);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4PCfE/

Answer (score 1):

```
var product_id=document.getElementById("one").value;
var version_id=document.getElementById("two").value;
var arch_id=document.getElementById("three").value;
```

something like this should work http://jsfiddle.net/9a8YH/4/